# ROI detection - Deep learning -References

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, roi

I know nothing on the subject of deep learning.

I am looking for references to **build a deep learning algorithm** to detect ROI in given images. My goal is to **compare deep learning algorithms with usual image processing algorithms I have already made**.
The input images look like this :

[image]

The output of the algorithm should look like this :

[image]

Q1: Do you have any **references** that if I read them would let me build such a **deep learning algorithm** from start to finish ?

Q2: Otherwise, do such algorithms already exist and are freely available ? (**Note:** Such algorithms should produce precise ROI detection not broad rectangles encircling the bright regions).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Mask R-CNN. Refer to these links for your understanding:

- https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06870

Basically, you need to make an annotation (polygonal) for your dataset with tools like VIA image annotation tool ([https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/software/via/)) or MakeSense (https://www.makesense.ai/). These are the open source tools that I can recommend. After training, the network can predict the bounding box as well as the boundary of the detected objects.

Answer (score -2):

Your task is easy, don't worry about knowing anything about the topic, as your image shows what you are trying to achieve, I would suggest you try using semantic segmentation, you can search on youtube or read about Faster R-CNNthey are kinda related to what you want to do. Then you can compare the output results with the regular image processing.

Comment: this answer adds no new information. it merely repeats some key points from an existing answer.